# iframe image disappears in ibooks

Tags: html, image, iframe, epub, ibooks

I have an iFrame containing a table with some questions / answers in ibooks, it's in the form of an epub, of course. I'm using an iframe because of the IOS 6 update fixing the `<input type="color">` workaround for bringing up the keyboard.

Anyhow, does anyone know the reason why everything would look good in the iframe, but when you look for the image it's "there" but it's not visible. That is, I can select it by double tapping, and it will highlight the area where it's supposed to be, but you won't physically be able to see the image.

I hope that's specific enough, let me know if you have any questions.